# Dynamically resized images for og:image ok?

Tags: facebook, image, facebook-opengraph

I use ImageResizer.net to create images to dimensions I need dynamically, based on one larger source image. It's done in a url-like fashion, like so: "www.siteUrl.com/ImagePath/ImageName.jpg?width=90&height=90&crop=auto&quality=90". This resizes the image to 90x90 pixels, cropping, and setting jpeg quality to 90%.

Will this url be acceptable to og:image , so that when someone likes/links to my content within Facebook it shows a thumbnail of the image inside the og:image property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this URL accepts og:image and works fine...

I have already used this like this eg. `<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.xyz.com/Handlers/ImageGenerator.ashx?id=de69f1e1-ee64-4bd9-80b8-8546bca4ef45&amp;w=50&amp;h=50" />`

Here i am using Image handler file and passing image id and image id is saved in my database associated with image path and it works fine on facebook....

Answer (score 2):

I've recently use URLs with some query string parameters for the og:image and it works fine for me.

In case you didn't know:

Facebook provides a debug tool, which allows you to check which OpenGraph meta data could be fetched from a certain domain: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Answer (score 1):

One note, Facebook wants the images to be at least 200px

Comment: As of today, according to http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/, the image must be at least 50x50, and according to http://developers.facebook.com/docs/share/ the image cannot excede 130x110.  However, if you use the URL Linter tool at http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug, it will warn that the image must be at least 200x200. Seems like conflicting documentation at Facebook, to me.

Comment: My experience is that an image 130x50 was cropped to a square rather than using as-is or resizing with aspect ratio intact.  I adjusted to 241x241 image and FB resized it and kept it as a square.  I experienced this while "Liking" a URL with an og:image meta tag and choosing to "Post" it on my wall with a comment, which is similar to the old "Share" feature.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work in my case.
Image is retrieved from MySQL blob field by asp script.
the debugger shows the image and gives no error but the button on the page doesn't take the image.

Page: http://www.ffkama.be/html/2_agenda_detail.asp?ps=id51

Image URL: http://www.ffkama.be/root/imager_ag.asp?id=51

UPDATE:
I forgot the code in the HEAD TAG :(
One thing is sure, without the 'prefix="og: h t tp://ogp.me/ns# fb: ht tp://ogp.me/ns/fb# website: h t tp://ogp.me/ns/website#"' in the HEAD Tag, the debugger doesn't give an arror and the image shows up in the dubugger but the image won't show up on your page. Then the page is cached and there are only 2 solutions:
1. rename the page
2. wait several days for the cache to expire