# Image cut-off when posting an open graph action

Tags: image, facebook-graph-api

I'm currently posting an action to the graph API, where the images being referenced are 120 x 55. This is above the 50 x 50 minimum, and below the 3:1 aspect ratio limit. The tags I'm using are:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.pickmoto.com/img/pennants/ravens_fb.png" />
<meta property="og:image:width" content="120" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="55" />
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/png" />
```

The image is showing up, but it's cut-off.  [image]

How do I fix this? I want the image to be legible at least. Is there a way to force facebook to shrink the image, or show it in the correct aspect ratio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to re-size the image. Increase the height without stretching the image (the way Photoshop handles *Canvas Resize*). To simplify things, some people do [image re-sizing on-the-fly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9030929/dynamically-resized-images-for-ogimage-ok).

Comment: Yep, I just ended up resizing the images to be square.